# Control DC MOTOR from headphone

Tags: motor, android

I would to know if is possible with simply way ( i'm not electronic expert ) to drive one direction a DC MOTOR ( a little ) from headphone, with power supply of course.

The difficulty is voltage of headphone, is very low 3mvw-6mw, is suppose is not enough to active logical input of L293.

I suppose is possible with transistor with "biais voltage", but how ?

I want to that because, I want to recycle my old android phone, into camera IP, rotate 380°, with eyefish.

I see it exist the IOIO board, but I think it is possible with cheaper parts.

Thanks by advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/is-it-possible-to-control-and-reverse-the-direction-of-a-dc-motor-through-a-head

Comment: I've seen it, I have not found an answer to my question is why I pose here. Thanks @Zuofu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an audio level detector.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDgbVq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- C1 blocks any DC from this circuit getting back to your phone.
- R2, R3 and C2 hold the '+' input at half-supply.
- R1 and R4 set the gain of the op-amp circuit to 10. (Actually it's -10 because it's inverted.)
- C4 blocks the DC from getting through to Q1.
- R5 slowly bleeds off C4 holding it at 0 V.
- D1 and C3 form a rectifier. When the audio signal exceeds the forward bias voltage of D1, C3 starts to charge up.
- If the audio level is high enough the voltage on C3 will rise enough to turn on Q1 pulling the 'on' output towards 0 V.

You'll need to choose an op-amp to suit your power supply.
Q1 will gradually turn off as when the audio stops. You may need to add a Schmitt trigger after it to provide a clean signal to your motor controller.

Make an audio signal that goes from off to full on to full off to switch the motor.

Comment: Thanks you for your complet reply ! I think your circuit is a bit complicated for my skill, but i keep your circuit it is very interessing. I would like to know i had purshase LM386 audio amp can i use it for control motor via pwm ? I think if i use LM386 the circuit will contain less parts no ?

Comment: I just discovery the LM3915 it used for display bar but if a replace led by motor , i can able to turn motor if a level of decibel no ?

Comment: If you find a circuit with audio input that will be fine. Replace the LED with an opto-isolator which has an LED on one side and a transistor on the other. Use the opto-transistor to switch a more powerful transistor to control the motor.

Answer (score 0):

How to drive a motor from LM3915

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK19OW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jasen i see the sheet and LM3915 seems to be have more pins, please can you explain me what is p1 and out ? Where can connect my + - from my headphone, and where connect my supply power to drive motor. Thanks by advance, and sorry for my somes mistakes, i'm french.

Comment: wire the rest as per datasheet, I'm just showing how to connect the motor to a LED output.

Comment: I just test your circuit on CircuitLab, can you add me the Voltage Function Generator generate at 0.5v and the power supply (to drive motor ) i don't know where to connect  the two. Thanks by advance

Comment: power supply is the top line, LM3915 looks like a small current source to ground that turns on and off, say 20mA on and 0mA off.

Comment: Have edited the schematic to allow somulation

Comment: Thanks you, i will try your schema when i receive lm3815 i also buy this http://m.ebay.com/itm/181725898206?_mwBanner=1 i think the ic will work too

Answer (score 0):

how would the phone produce the sound that is needed by the circuit?

would you call it and it would auto-answer, then you would send it the sound?

it may be possible to attach light sensors onto the screen and control the motor by displaying areas of varying brightness on the screen

you could set the phone to display a webpage (with auto refresh) that is served by your computer

the webpage would be a simple black and white picture

then changing the webpage on your computer would control the phone

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i think is not a good because the screen drain alot power from the battery. I did think generate sound via Tasker when i receive a SMS content. Link SMS "turn left" phone will play 400hz sound frequency. Or turn right another frequency.